# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'drupal'

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a MySQL server I haven't configured my self and I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to SQL.

I've created a database like this:

```
root@localhost:~# mysqladmin -u root -p create drupal
```

And then tried to grant privileges like this:

```
root@localhost:~# mysql -u root -p

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON drupal.* TO root IDENTIFIED BY ...;
```

But get this error:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'drupal'
```

[Update] I get this error with all forms of GRANT commands.

But according to SHOW GRANTS I should have privileges:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                            
|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 
'*...' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL version is: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB
On Debian 9.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the root user didn't have Grant privileges.

```
SELECT host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
```

I fixed it with this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

You have to log out and in again for it to work.